# Absolute path not allowed on row 7, xml to postgres?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION j_f_sync_from_xml()
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
myxml    xml;
datafile text := 
'C:\Users\Polichetti\Documents\ABBATE_EMANUELE_Lvl1F2Va_20160418-1759.xml';
BEGIN

myxml := pg_read_file(datafile, 0, 100000000); 

CREATE TABLE james AS
SELECT (xpath('//some_id/text()', x))[1]::text AS id
FROM   unnest(xpath('/xml/path/to/datum', myxml)) x;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
SELECT * from james;
```

I find an error, absolute path not allowed on row 7.
 Probably I don't know which path I have to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE

> Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory
>   can be accessed. Use a relative path for files in the cluster
>   directory, and a path matching the log_directory configuration setting
>   for log files.

you can access just any OS file, run `show data_directory` and `show log_directory` o find out where you can read file with `pg_read_file`

If you want to load xml to db, I'd rather use different approach, eg:

```
create table xml(body text);
copy xml from '/absolute/path/to/file.xml';
select string_agg(body,'')::xml from xml;
```

this is the easiest example. you can look on the web for more, eg [using large objects](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5D5B211D-317B-4A62-B625-C2D28323DAFD%40gmx.net) utils

Comment: I tried datafile test := 'ABBATE_EMANUELE_Lvl1F2Va_20160418-1759.xml' and I insert the file xml in the path but I have an error not find the flie